# ADSI Edit on Windows Server 2012 R2: Can't find domain

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to test System Center Configuration Manager to update one of my Windows 10 devices (because our clients are using this method), and I'm trying to deploy this on a Windows Server 2012 R2 to push these updates to the Windows 10 device. At the moment, I'm running this server on a Hyper-V virtual machine (I don't have any server hardware that I can use to deploy it).

I'm following [this tutorial](https://prajwaldesai.com/installing-prerequisites-for-configuration-manager-2012-r2/), and in one of the steps, I need to use the ADSI Edit tool. When I'm in the Connection Settings window and press OK, I get the following error: **Operation failed. Error code: 0x8007054b The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.**
[image]

I have found [something](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1726627-the-specified-domain-either-does-not-exist-or-could-not-be-contacted) on the Internet telling me I have to change a value in the registry keys (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters\SysvolReady) from 0 to 1, but this key doesn't exist, and adding it doesn't do anything either.

I also found that it could have something to do with it not finding any DNS servers. With DHCP activated and with a static IP configuration (I used the DNS server of my office), it didn't work either. It can however connect to a website (I tried surfing to google.com and it worked).

Comment: Does your environment have a AD controller? Do you have any reason to not follow the official documentation?

Comment: No, it didn't have an AD controller. And the reason I'm not using the official documentation (as far as there is one) is that Microsoft documentation always skips 5 steps in their explanation. I don't know anything about Windows server, so I needed a clearer tutorial. I currently have installed the feature and I'm working out how to configure it (again, I don't know anything about Windows server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Seth](https://superuser.com/users/619267/seth) I figured out the problem. I didn't have a AD controller deployed on my server.

Comment: Cool, can you add the steps you took to rectify the situation? I'll certainly up vote your answer if you do.